# Dialogflow ES custom events not firing when called

Tags: dialogflow-es, voximplant

I have a Dialogflow ES agent and have set up a custom event up with the agent.

However, when this event is called nothing happens. I know the function that calls it is working as it works when I set the event to the default welcome event.

I added the custom event by just typing the name I wanted for the event in the 'Event' section on Dialogflow ES like this:

[image]

The function that is triggering the event is from Voximplant and is set up like this:

```
dialogflow.sendQuery({ event: { name: "Email", language_code: "en-GB", parameters: { dtmf_digits: toneString } } })
```

When I change the code to the following to use the default welcome event it all works fine:

```
dialogflow.sendQuery({ event: { name: "Welcome", language_code: "en-GB", parameters: { dtmf_digits: toneString } } })
```

Am I setting up the event wrong in Dialogflow? I assumed I could just type the name I wanted for the custom event and start using it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I set the context for the intent I wanted the event to trigger to be the same as the event and this all worked fine.